# Where do I ask a question regarding the credibility of a fact that is widely mentioned over the web, yet cannot be verified easily?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where can I ask the following question which needs to deal with "hoax or truth", and if it's a hoax, then it's propagating incredibly in a very populous country, providing its people false information and pride.

---

I came to notice through a Facebook post that a renowned scientist and former President of India Mr A.P.J. Adbul Kalam passed away. When I tried to look upon [his Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A._P._J._Abdul_Kalam) I noticed this line:

> Kalam's 79th birthday was recognised as *World Student Day* by the United Nations.

The source backing that claim is [here](http://www.thehindu.com/todays-paper/tp-national/tp-tamilnadu/students-recall-kalams-services/article837169.ece), whose content doesn't shed any light on whether UN really recognized that day or not. On further research over web, I found various links which claimed this fact. **It is to be noted that** all those links were either from Indian people, Indian media, Indian websites, or things dominantly dealing with Indian matters. '[Indian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/India)' here refers to a South Asian and second largest populated Country in the world.

Failing to find an authentic source, I tried to find what is *World Student Day*. Here are some sources that I found:

- [World Student Day](http://ifesworld.org/en/node/53) (from IFES)
- [Oct 17 – World Student Day](http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~hrcf/?p=174) (from Harvard-Radcliffe Christian Fellowship)
- [World Student Day 2015](http://languagescanada.ca/en/language-education-sector/sector-activities/) (from  Languages Canada)

None of them mentioned the term *United Nations (UN)* anywhere in the text.

I lastly looked at the days of [International Observance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_observance) and found the only mention of the word 'Student' in this line:

> November 17   International Students Day

The wiki page of [International Students Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Students%27_Day) again has no mention of Mr Kalam, neither it says that UN has officially observed it.

UNESCO also on its page of [International Days](http://www.unesco.org/new/en/unesco/events/prizes-and-celebrations/celebrations/international-days/) has no mention of the word *Student*.

So, what exactly is this *World Student Day*? Did UN really observe Mr Kalam's 79<sup>th</sup> birthday as *World Student Day*? Where is the authentic source to back any of the claims?

**Edit**: [Asked it](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3326/27317) on Skeptics Meta  after considering suggestion in the Comment and the Answer

Comment: Finally [asked it](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/28600/27317) on [Skeptics.se] and made required changes to keep it on-topic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) might fit, since their help reads (emphasis mine):

> Skeptics is about applying skepticism — it is for **researching the evidence behind claims you encounter**.

So indeed, Skeptics can help clear this one out. To be sure, please visit their [meta](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com) and ask there if the question is allowed.

(I was misreading their help first, I do agree it should fit)

Comment: I upvoted this since you suggested their meta to know whether it really belongs there or not.

Comment: @Arch that is an easy one. It is like a disclaimer ;)